# Paypal express checkout VAT show 0.00

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I made one transaction using PayPal Express Checkout , it showing VAT but after logged PayPal account in transaction detail page VAT value showing 0.00 , any one know what is issue ? , i used PayPal express checkout sample code.

Comment: Did you got any answer?